# In a Golang app, SASL auth succeeds when passing variables to the process, but fails when exported variables are used. Why?

Tags: postgresql, go, ssl, go-gorm

We have a Golang app built with Gorm that connects with PostgreSQL 14 (hosted in the same machine) with an SSL mode of `verify-full`. The certificates were issued by ZeroSSL, and generated with the help of Acme.sh. In the PostgreSQL configuration, we have set the following certificate-related variables:

```
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/our-certificate.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/our-certificate.key'
```

The Golang app and the PostgreSQL server are hosted in an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Our Golang app depends on a bunch of environment variables for, among others, database passwords and usernames. When we pass those variables to our app directly, i.e.:

```
DB_HOST=dbhost DB_NAME=dbname DB_USERNAME=username DB_PASSWORD=123456789 [...] ./go-app
```

Everything works well.

On the other hand, we also tried `export`ing those variables first. Exporting the variables is done by putting the variables inside an `env` file first, then doing the following:

```
set -a
source env-file.env
set +a
```

The environment variables are exported now at this point, and we can echo the variables from the terminal.

Unfortunately, when our Golang app reaches the point where it would attempt to connect with the PostgreSQL server, we would get the following error message:

```
error="failed to connect to `host=dbhost user=username database=dbname`: failed SASL auth (FATAL: password authentication failed for user \"username\" (SQLSTATE 28P01))"
```

I have already logged the contents of the exported database-related environment variables to the console, and they were of the same values as the variables directly passed to the process.

Why does this happen? It's a weird behaviour for me, but I believe I am simply lacking some necessary information.

Comment: Quite likely your env-file variables are incorrect, or they are not exported or sourced properly. Hard to tell without seeing the contents of the file and the sequence of steps taken to source it and execute your app. You can debug this yourself however by updating your Go code with a log statement that prints the db specific environment variables to stdout just before attempting to connect to the db with those variables. Now execute your app with the pass-vars-directly approach and the export-from-env-file approach. Look for differences between the two outputs.

Comment: Hey, @mkopriva! I forgot to mention that I did log the relevant exported environment variables to `stdout` inside the app, and confirmed that it was the correct value. Adding this part to the post.

Comment: Does you `env-file.env` file contain only those 4 `DB_XYZ` variables? Or are there other variables that may cause the Go app to behave differently? If so try commenting out all the other variables so that only the db specific ones are exported.